# UIButton with highlight image that is bigger than frame

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uibutton

Is it possible for a `UIButton` to have a highlight image that is larger than the `UIButton's` `frame` (I want to keep `UIButton's` `frame` so that it's the size of the `UIControlStateNormal` image, not the `UIControlStateHighlight` image).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that is possible:

```
button.imageView?.contentMode = .center
button.imageView?.clipsToBounds = false
```